# MemcachedOperationException: Failed to get key

Tags: memcached

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.sixhours.memcached.cache.MemcachedOperationException: Failed to get key

Comment: Please include the code that's causing the error.

Comment: Please do add the code else it is not possible to know whats the leading to this Exception